# Redisson: Why reactive client doesn't have PermitExpirableSemaphore?

Tags: redisson

I am using redisson reactive Java client. In non reactive client one could get an expirable Semaphore as:-

`RPermitExpirableSemaphore semaphore = redisson.getPermitExpirableSemaphore("mySemaphore");`

But If I create a reactive client, I can only find `redisson.getSemaphore("value")` function. I need PermitExpirableSemaphore because:-

1. I need a lock which could be released by different thread(so can't use `RLock`).
2. I need a lease timeout to prevent deadlock in case the lock aquiring thread is killed or stuck.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior in Redisson Distributed Locking?

**Edit1**: I can set lease time global in Config as:- `Config().setLockWatchdogTimeout(leaseTimeMs)`, but I really need different leasetime at different locks.

**Edit2**: Asked a question on Redisson github at https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/1391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As linked in the **edit2**, there was no way of doing this in Redisson. Nikita, who is lead developer of Redisson quickly introduced the requested feature, to be launched in `2.11.6`.